# Insert vector in DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a DataFrame Df => `dim(Df) = 3243 679`

I would like to change a part of my dataframe for exemple:

```
Df[50:100,1] = c(...)
```

with `c(...)` corresponding to a vector of 50 elements.

Is there a better way to do it because it doesn't work

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 50:100, 1, value = c("27.4349976",  : 
  replacement has 50 rows, data has 3243
```

Comment: Actually, `length(50:100)` is 51, not 50. I cannot reproduce the error, everything works as expected when replacing a segment of a dataframe column vector.

Comment: 51 if you want it does not really change my problem

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(Df[49:101, 1:2])`?

Comment: Not reproducible, it works in my case, please check the length of the RHS expression (`c(...)`, has it the same length as 50:100 -> 51 elements?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your vector to be inserted has fewer elements than necessary. 50: 100 are 51 elements.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(n = 1000),
                 b = rnorm(n = 1000),
                 c = rnorm(n = 1000))

insert <- c(runif(n = 51))

df[50:100,1] <- insert
```

Comment: I guess this is the right answer to the wrong question ;-)

Comment: I did not understand. Could you make it clearer @RYoda?

Comment: I edited. I made it simpler and using the same method.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my comment is clear: The question is, how to insert data into a `data.frame`, your answer is so complex and uses a `ggplot` (not asked in the question) that I guess you have prepared an answer for another question but have pasted it into this (wrong) question...